# Calling slack api for data from specific time range

Tags: slack-api, slack

Can you do that? If so, how? I'm using some of the methods here https://api.slack.com/methods but I haven't found any information about using time range as an argument.

Comment: Yes, but it depends on what data you want to retrieve. Please be more specific in your question about what kind of data you need to get for a specific time range.

Answer (score 0):

When I asked that question I had believed you should ask about date range using extra args field so I had felt like I was specific enough. I believe Slack API docs does not document such use cases as getting date range. Good thing is that there is a tester on the https://api.slack.com/ page.

To get time ranges you need a method that supports that.

Here is an example of such method:

`https://api.slack.com/methods/im.history/test`